# Tailwind custom Font being removed from Plugin

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css

I have successful loaded in two custom font to my codebase that is using tailwind. My issue is that when I use a plugin to create a base set of styles for my HTML the custom font is ignored then is reverted to the back up.

This only happens when I use the theme directory callback in the plugin. If I hardcode the fontFamily name in there then it works correctly.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/**
 * Configuration
 */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      display: ['New Grotesk', 'arial'],
      body: ['Founders Grotesk', 'arial']
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    globalStyles,
  ],
}
```

**Plugin**

```
const globalStyles = ({ addBase, config }) => {
  addBase({
    'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5': {
      marginBottom: config('theme.margin.2'),
      lineHeight: config('theme.lineHeight.tight'),
      fontFamily: config('theme.fontFamily.display')
    },
  });
}
```

If I swap out `fontFamily: config('theme.fontFamily.display')` for `fontFamily: 'New Grotesk'`. It works correctly but this defeats the purpose of using the config function.

I know this is a possible extending the `@base` scss but I would prefer to do it this way.

Here is a screenshot of the fontFamily being ignored by my browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the need to add double quotes in your `font-family` stack when using a font that has a space in the name:

```
// Won't work
fontFamily: {
  display: ['New Grotesk', 'arial'],
}

// Add quotes :
fontFamily: {
  display: ['"New Grotesk"', 'arial'],
}
```

Ref: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#font-families